# How to neglect scroll bars eventhough the autoscroll property is true?

Tags: extjs4

In extjs form, how to neglect the horizontal scroll bar eventhough the autoscroll property is true?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
autoScroll: false,
overflowX: 'hidden',
overflowY: 'auto'
```

Comment: But I want autoScroll: true.

Comment: but `autoscroll: true` is for both scrollbars and you only want one scrollbar and this will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`autoScroll: true` is equivalent to:

```
overflowX: 'auto',
overflowY: 'auto'
```

So, if you just want the vertical scrollbar to be displayed, simply use the following instead of `autoScroll: true`:

```
overflowX: 'hidden',
overflowY: 'auto'
```

Take a look at the documentation if you want more info:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-autoScroll
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-overflowX
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-overflowY